# <%# Bind("Name") %> parameters asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I've seen this binding `<%# Bind("Name") %>` a lot but what is the `Name` field? Is that the name of the column? The ID of the row/ gridview? Or the field in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out it's the name of the column in the `Datasource`